# Login and Reload JBoss server using Java

Tags: java, jboss

I am trying to login to my `JBoss server` using Java and reload it.
I have tried following code:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\jboss\\jboss-eap-6.4\\bin\\jboss-cli.bat -c --controller=10.10.10.10 --user=user --password=pass --command=:reload");

    processBuilder.inheritIO();
    Process p = processBuilder.start();
    try {
        p.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but I get this error:

```
CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

I have following settings for my environment variables-
1. `JAVA_HOME- C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121`
2. `JBOSS_HOME-C:\jboss\jboss-eap-6.4`
3.  The bat file is present in the directory
4.  I can login and reload it manually

I am out of ideas here.

Comment: Don't pass a single `String` to `ProcessBuilder`'s constructor, pass it a `List` or array of tokens composed of the command path and its various arguments.

Comment: Do you mean something like this- ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\jboss\\jboss-eap-6.4\\bin\\jboss-cli.bat"," -c"," --controller=10.10.10.10"," --user=user"," --password=pass","--command=:reload");  .... this does not work too and throws the same error

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. It's possible Java doesn't know how to execute a `.bat` file, you can try adding `cmd` and `/C` at the start of your argument list, which should make `cmd` execute the batch script with the provided arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec()
```

instead of

```
processBuilder()
```